# When are maps between Hom sets induced?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I'm trying to better understand $R$-module homomorphisms, and I know that say, an $\, f:M\to N$ induces $\, f_*:Hom_R(V,M)\to Hom_R(V,N)$ or $\, f^*:Hom_R(N,V)\to Hom_R(M,V)$. What I'm wondering is, for any group homomorphism $\, \psi:Hom_R(V,M)\to Hom_R(V,N)$, is there necessarily such an $f$ so that $\psi=f_*$?

If not, what's a counter-example, or what other conditions are necessary?

Answer (score 1):

$\psi$ could also precompose with any homomorphism $V \to V$, which is likely to ruin any chances of it being an $f_*$.

For example, let $V = R^2$, $M = N = R$. Let $\psi = s^*$, where $s(\langle x,y \rangle) = \langle y,x \rangle$.

Now let $\pi_1$ be the first projection, $\pi_1(\langle x, y \rangle) = x$: I claim $\pi_1 \in \mathrm{Hom}_R(R^2, R)$.

Then $\psi(\pi_1) = \pi_2$. But no matter what you post-compose $\pi_1$ with, you can't get $\pi_2$, because $\pi_1$ flat-out ignores the second component.

Now, can all homomorphisms $\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}_R(C,D)$ be written as $f_* \circ g^*$ for suitable $f$ and $g$? I don't know. I suspect the answer is still no, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Consider the case that $A,B,C,D$ are finitely generated free.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I just tried generalizing for a counterexample to the $f_*\circ g^*$ approach for f.g. free $A,B,C,D$ without success... Not my original question, but now my curiosity is piqued.